# I'm trying to understand which cryptographic algorithm is this

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design

I'm reversing a cryptographic algorithm. This is part of the encryption function translated to python (starting from assembly code):

```
cleartext = [ 0x24,0x11,0x33,0x63,0xbc,0x59,0x07,0x5b,0x96,0x4b,0x07,0x15,0x2d,0x23,0x4b,0x70 ]
clearlen = 16

# Init the dictionary
cdict = [ 0 ] * 256
for i in range(256):
  cdict[i] = i

v1 = 0
# Load the dictionary
for i in range(256):
  v1 += (cleartext[ i % clearlen ] + cdict[i])
  v1 = v1 & 0xFF
  v2 = cdict[v1] ^ cdict[i]
  cdict[i] = v2
  v3 = cdict[v1] ^ v2
  cdict[v1] = v3
  cdict[i] ^= v3
```

Then this array of 256 bytes is used to extract *clearlen* bytes which are XORed with a key. I didn't translate it to python yet.

I was trying to understand if this was a known cryptographic algorithm, or it is completely custom. So far I was not able to identify it. Do you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would appear to be [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), which is a well known (if not well trusted) cryptographical algorithm, original designed by Ron Rivest.

The part you quoted is the Key Setup Algorithm, which is run before you actually encrypt/decrypt anything.  The part which is written in an unusual (but correct) way is the last 5 lines, which does a swap of `cdict[i]` and `cdict[v1]` - more typically, it is written with just 2 reads and 2 writes and two temp variables in the obvious fashion; for some reason they decided to use some 'clever' logic with xors (and two temp variables, 4 reads, 3 writes).

Comment: gosh, you are right! Or at least...partially right, but now I understand more. There is one difference which didn't allowed me to recognize it: this initialization in RC4 is done with the key, not with the clear text (like in this case)...but these can be swapped, so I think that you put me on the right path. Thanks!

Comment: @cips: it would appear that the programmer tried to put in some small effort to make it less obvious what they're doing; calling the key the 'cleartext', and doing the swap in an obscure way.  Or did you insert the variable names?

Comment: I actually inserted the variable name, based on the usage of the variable in the program, or at least on what I thought it was the usage. But you are probably right, it was a kind of obfuscation. Thanks!